# How to test high level Qt plugins?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, user-interface

I have an applications which loads few Qt high level dll's. These dll's are implemented using Qt plugin framework. I have plugin loader class which loads the plugins and casts to interfaces.

I want to test the interface and plugins loaded by the application. The plugin loader class has some basic test like dll counts implemented using GTest but rest I do not know which framework to use. Can anyone suggest a solution.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is so general there is no good answer. It's not clear what you want to test for

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about the plugins being plugins. Test them like you would test any other `QObject`-based interface. Qt Test module is a good default choice. It's used to test Qt builds themselves, too, so it's not some half-supported also-ran.